# TestNG gives "Connection Refused" while running on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium-rc, testng

I'm trying to run Selenium tests with Selenium-RC using TestNG on Eclipse. When I try to run a test, I get something like the following console output:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot establish connection: 127.0.0.1:1613
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.StringMessageSenderHelper.connect(StringMessageSenderHelper.java:94)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:71)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:144)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.StringMessageSenderHelper.connect(StringMessageSenderHelper.java:56)
    ... 2 more
```

It doesn't seem to matter whether the Selenium-RC server is running or not.  The latest TestNG plugin is installed in Eclipse, and I have the Selenium Java driver included in the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that TestNG was unaware of the correct server location.  I have a local Tomcat server running in Eclipse located under the workspace metadata.  I added the following setUp() method, where `my.local.host` is the location of my server:

```
@BeforeTest
@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
   setUp("http://my.local.host:5555/", "*firefox");
}
```

After adding this the test case ran successfully.